# How to count number of genuine online visitors?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm developing an application to store total visitors visiting to my website using set_cookie(). But while developing that application, I've a second thought regarding the issue, that if the user is visits from the another system how can I track him.

Confused What I mean?

Dont worry, I'll Explain.

Lets imagine a person is visiting my website through a system  and my code will recognise this person and will store his ip address to the database and count as a new user.No problem. But this person is visiting from another pc/mobile/tab it will also count as a new user.

I dont want to use login system.
Is there any way to prevent this? Any idea?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a multi-million dollar problem, mapping users across devices. One way of doing it, though I can't really say how ethical it is, is by using user's logged in status with Facebook or Google or other such services across devices.

Comment: Voting does not involve manners in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can't detect a person only you can detect  ip address ..but if you make a logging system then you can detect person correctly no matter from what machine he logged..and if you use ip you can get only mean value about how much people navigate to your site

Answer (score 2):

**Use a cookie to identify unique users, and then just keep track of the last time accessed a PHP page. Then come up with a timeout mechanism - for example, if they have not accessed a page in 15 minutes then they are removed from the count.**

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way of achieving without making fool of privacy. Provide an authentication mechanism so that only logged in users can see your site. That way, you will have the information.

If you don't want to create a seperate user id and password and maintain them, use something like OpenID so that if a user wishes to identify himself, he will do so.

Trying to identify a user without their agreement may be illegal in some parts of the world.

Comment: what you mean by authentication mechanism ?

Comment: I meant providing username and password to the user and creating a login form where he can login to your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reliably track unique users via a login system, yours or others. IP addresses are often assigned dynamically, so the same user on the same device will have a different IP the next time they visit.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply show your user count. Or if your site doesn't contain user login facility then there is no other way then except ip address here is the code for that

```
$log = 'count.log';//create a log file name count
$IP = getenv (REMOTE_ADDR);// get ip address
$add = true;
$hits = 0;
if (!file_exists ($log)) {
    echo "Error: $log does not exist.";
    exit;
}
$h = fopen ($log, 'r');
while (!feof ($h)) {
    $line = fgets ($h, 4096);
    $line = trim ($line);
    if ($line != '')
        $hits++;

    if ($line == $IP)
        $add = false;
}

fclose($h);

if ($add == true) {
    $h = fopen ($log, 'a');
    fwrite($h, "$IP");
    fclose($h);
    $hits++;
}

echo $hits;
```

Include this file in your page where you want to show counter

Comment: written in comment it will get your system ip address